# Android SQLite throws Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Today I wanted to implement a simple SQLite database into my messaging app that should take care of saving messages, unfortunately I am not able to read back the data from the Database and display them into a ListView.

I looked into the database via ADB on my emulator and I saw that the data is saved correctly.

Here is my code

Initialisation of the TABLE with a empty column

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Messages(zero);");
```

Creating of a column with the chat contact as the column name

```
public void addMessagetoDB(String message, String from) {
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "msg msg", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    try
    {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Messages ADD COLUMN '" + from + "' TEXT");
    }
    catch (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException e)
    {

    }
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Messages ('" + from + "') VALUES('" + message + "');");
}
```

Here I can also see that SQLite recognizes my column names, because when I send multiple messages to my client I get the debug messages

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) duplicate column name: test@zapp.org
```

This is my readout which won't work

```
public void updateView(String from) {
        Cursor crs = zapp.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Messages", null);
        while (crs.moveToNext()) {
            String name = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(from));
            messages.add(name);
        }
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is my exception

```
06-05 22:15:45.841    4926-4926/? E/SQLiteCursor﹕ requesting column name with table name -- test@zapp.org
    java.lang.Exception
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteCursor.java:180)
            at org.reisacher.zapp.ChatActivity.updateView(ChatActivity.java:43)
            at org.reisacher.zapp.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-05 22:15:45.841    4926-4926/? E/CursorWindow﹕ Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 5 rows, 2 columns.
06-05 22:15:45.841    4926-4926/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-05 22:15:45.841    4926-4926/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.reisacher.zapp, PID: 4926
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
            at org.reisacher.zapp.ChatActivity.updateView(ChatActivity.java:43)
            at org.reisacher.zapp.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

As one can see SQLite is trying to get the column name, which matches the one I am saving the messages to, but the somehow then reads column -1

I didn't find a solution for this behavior

Thanks

Comment: Did you somehow named one of the columns: "test@zapp.org"? 
Maybe by mistake you try to retrieve data using this email(/id)?

I ask because it seems like you invoke method updateView(String from) with this email as a parameter. 

[code] requesting column name with table name -- test@zapp.org[cod]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the you have a '.' in the field name and that is being understood by the engine as a table.field separator.

In other words, getColumnIndex() is trying to find the numeric index of 'org' in the table 'test@zapp' ... another reason to not use that type of value for your field names.

The clue that gave it away was the "E/SQLiteCursor﹕ requesting column name with table name -- test@zapp.org"

I would also question your idea of dynamically adding columns to the table based on the 'from' value, growing your table horizontally instead of the normal method of letting it expand vertically. Makes it slower and slower as it gets bigger and more unwieldy.

Comment: Thanks, that got it working, substringed the "from" value at the "@" character. What do you mean by expanding it vertically. I am adding a column for a contact, then the messages from or to that contact are being added below in the corresponding column making the table grow vertically